# linkage issue(i think) in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I writing a game in AS3 using flash. The game works, and I'm trying to add music to the game.

I added a mp3 file called Music (linkage Music.mp3)
and I added in the board (which is the whole game ) the following lines

```
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
public var music:Music;
public var bgmSoundChannel:SoundChannel;
```

I'm getting error

> Type was not found or was not a compile time constant:Music

I had some problems before while trying to use more then one class its seems the my classes doesn't see other classes defined in my fla.

I will be happy to find a solution, and if you know a good explanation about as3 architecture I will be happy to get a link for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `Music` is not found as a compile-time class.  This is most likely because you have not correctly set its class in the linkage box.

You say its linkage is `Music.mp3`. This must be `Music` in order for your code to work.

Comment: thank u its working now can u recommend me a link about as3 architecture?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're looking for? Filesystem layout, design patterns?

Comment: i'm looking for how the main loop works,explanation about the terms document, stage and root, and recommendation for designing an application..(this game was only one class, i know its not a good idea but i had difficulties with the linkages)